# How to retrieve this data without transforming it in memory?

Tags: java, mysql

Often I need to select all the data from two tables which have an association. I do this by doing 2 `select *` queries and then merging the results together in memory. Is there a good option to do this in sql and avoid the in-memory transformation, while still executing, at most, 2 queries?

I would like to retrieve all Users and their associated key, value pairs.

results:

```
users:[
  {
    userId: 1
    name: tom
    otherUserData: [
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
    ]
  },
  {
    userId: 2
    name: jane
    otherUserData: [
      key3: value3
      key4: value4
    ]
  },
]
```

data:

```
Users
-----------------
userId | userName 
-----------------
1      | tom
2      | jane

OtherUserData
-----------------
userId | Key | Value 
-----------------
1      | key1  | value1
1      | key2  | value2
2      | key3  | value3
2      | key4  | value4
```

`

```
class User {
  String id;
  String name;
  Map<String, String> otherUserData;
}

Map userRecordsById = new HashMap<>();

List userResults = query("select * from Users");
for (SqlRecord record : userResults) {
  User user = new User(record("userId"), record("userName");
  userRecordsById.put(user.id, user);
}

List otherDataResults = query("select * from OtherUserData");
for (SqlRecord record : otherDataResults) {
  User user = userRecordsById.get(record("userId"));
  if (user != null) {
    user.otherUserData(record.get("key"), record.get("value"));
  }
}

return userRecordsById.values();
```

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL JOINs?

Comment: SQL is THE language to use in this situation. So I would let the database doing the work

Comment: ***Is there a good option to do this in sql and avoid the in-memory transformation, while still executing, at most, 2 queries?***  Yes, and no.   The database server will do this in memory... it has to.  However that's what SQL is all about retrieving data in a relational database though  ANSI standard joins: Start with [Coding horror blog](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) to learn about Joins.  this can be done in 1 query in SQL by joining the two tables on their Primary key/Foreign key relationship.

Comment: I think you are missing something with the joins.. If I do a join I will get 4 results, one for each entry in OtherUserData. I will then have to process this  in a similar way to merge the related OtherUserData?

Comment: But what is the rule here; you only take the first one for each user, why ? on what order ?

Comment: @AxelH No, I return all Users with all their OtherData. Does the 'results' section clarify this?

Comment: Ok, wasn't clear with your previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I would let the SQL to do the job. Using a JOIN (See Jordan S answer).My answer will only explain how to read the `ResultSet` because in comment this will become messy

You only need to order the result by `Users.userId` and loop on the ResultSet by checking if the userId as changed. Here is a small pseudo-code to explain the idea.

```
for each row in ResultSet
    if row['userId'] <> userId
        userId = row['userId']
        user = new User(row);
    user.add(new UserData(row));
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement will join your tables:

`SELECT * FROM Users LEFT JOIN OtherUserData ON Users.userId = OtherUserData.userId;`

Comment: But this will give 4 results instead of 2, one for each OtherUserData? And then I will have to process the results in a similar way to my code?

Comment: Correct. But you are reduced to one query.

Comment: What if Users is has a bunch of columns I need to select, and OtherUserData has many rows for each User. Would one query still be preferred when most of the data for each result would be repeated?